# Freezing flavored/infused oils

Tags: storage-method, freezing, oil, storage, infusion

I'm looking to make a variety of infused oils (lemon zest infused, garlic confit oil, herb oil, etc--all strained with no solids left) to have on hand. Unfortunately, most recipes recommend to use infused oils within one week, which 
in most cases would not be possible in my case. I'd like to make a batch of each and keep them for longer, if possible. Would it be feasible to freeze oils like this with minimal loss in quality? If it would ruin the flavor/aroma of volatile compounds found in lemon rind and herbs, I'm not sure it's worth it, but wanted to see if anyone else has had success here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine. In fact, there is advice on preserving fresh herbs by freezing them in ice cube trays filled with oil - I tried it once, and enjoyed the results. So I'm pretty sure the flavored oil will also keep well. Maybe not as perfect as on the first day, but still plenty of aroma.

Comment: Much appreciated!